# Reading HTM file: mysterious white space around every character

Tags: html, regex, perl

I have an HTM file. When I open it directly in Notepad, it looks like this:

```
<HTML>
<BODY BGCOLOR=#FFFFFF BGPROPERTIES=FIXED>
<FONT 000000 FACE=ARIAL SIZE=3>
<HEAD>
```

When I attempt to do this in Perl:

```
open (my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Error opening file! $!";
chomp(my @lines = <$fh>);
close $fh;
```

Each line in the Perl array now has these extra spaces and looks like this:

```
< H T M L >    
< B O D Y   B G C O L O R = # F F F F F F   B G P R O P E R T I E S = F I X E D >    
< F O N T   0 0 0 0 0 0   F A C E = A R I A L   S I Z E = 3 >    
< H E A D >
```

Any ideas on where the problem is?

CLARIFICATION: These are not my HTM files, so I have no control over them or their creation. I receive the file and must process the contents. Various attacks like `s/ (?= |\w)//g` don't seem to affect this mysterious whitespace.

The output is being generated this way:

```
foreach (@lines) {
    $line .= "$_\n";
}

open( $fh, '>', 'output-file.txt' ) or die "Could not open file $!";
print $fh $line;
close $fh;
```

Comment: check how your editor treats spaces, line-breaks and stuff. Also check the encoding you use in every environment or at least post this info.

Comment: How are you getting the spaced output?

Comment: What's the encoding of the file? Make sure it's not encoded as UTF-16, or if it is, make sure you properly decode it when reading. Also, it might help if you showed us how you actually print the data and anything relevant that happens between the code you quoted and when you print it. Also, run the output of the script through hexdump to see what those spaces actually are.

Comment: I am concatenating each array element to a string directly with no changes (until I can figure this spacing issue out). Then I write to a file with `open ( $fh, '>', 'filename.txt' ); print $fh $line;`

Comment: Those are not spaces but null bytes. That's why `s/ //` doesn't work. The file is encoded as UTF-16 (each character is stored on 2 bytes). The best usage for Notepad on such situation is to save the file as UTF-8 (but other editors may do the job faster and better.)

Comment: Is there a way to remove these null bytes directly in Perl?

Comment: `.HTM` extension + `BGPROPERTIES` + `<FONT>` + HTML tags in uppercase => Welcome to 1997!

Comment: I cannot tell for Perl but in PHP I would use `iconv()` to change the string encoding from `UTF16-LE` to `UTF8`. But wait, there is an `iconv` program on macOS and Linux that can be used to do just that!

Comment: I found a solution `@lines = map { s/\000//r } @lines;` The result: my output is now literally in Chinese characters.

Comment: If that is your desired result... take a look at File::BOM or Encode qw(from_to) or Text::Iconv. as always with perl.. timtowtdi.

Comment: hexdump on your original file would be quite helpful...

Comment: The first thing I thought was that it's split up into individual chars and then the resulting array is interpolated into a string, resulting in the spaced because of `$,`. But that's clearly not the case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no text but encoded text. Every file is written with one specific character encoding and must be read with that same encoding.

HTML files are formatted text. They have a document encoding—the one the file is written with. The document "value" is a sequence of Unicode characters. If the file doesn't use a Unicode encoding, characters can be represented as numeric character entities (e.g., &#x1f6b2; instead of ). They also have a mechanism to indicate the document encoding internally ([meta charset](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations)), but, apparently, that was not used.

When you receive a text file, you must also have knowledge of which encoding was used to write it. If you don't have that, it's a failed communication. (Web servers and browsers prevent that by telling each other which encoding they are using with the HTTP [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) heading. Unfortunately, with programs dropping files into the filesystem of a single system, there has been too much reliance on defaults or "detection" [informed guessing].)

As others have said, it looks like your text renderer is coping with UTF-16 encoded text by emitting a space where it sees a zero byte. (I wonder how it would deal with .) People are asking for a hex dump of your bytes so they can improve the guess. If it is consistent with UTF-16, that would be a highly probable guess, even with such a small sample.

The solution is simple: Confirm with the sender that the encoding is UTF-16 and then read it as UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE depending on the byte ordering. The byte ordering is easy to detect, given the knowledge that the encoding is UTF-16. So, slurp the file as a byte string and decode the bytes into a text string using [Encode::Unicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode/Unicode.html#Size%2c-Endianness%2c-and-BOM).

Answer (score -1):

I applied `s/\x0//g` which apparently transformed many nulls into Chinese characters. I cleaned these out with `s/[^[:ascii:]]+//g;`. It isn't ideal but seems to work.